# Do you need Xcode to program iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipod

I'm interested in making apps for the iphone. I was wondering if it were possible to make apps, WITHOUT Xcode. the only reason is because I'm dirt poor, and can't afford an Apple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Programming in Mac OS X runnning not in a Mac Computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133402/iphone-programming-in-mac-os-x-runnning-not-in-a-mac-computer)

Comment: It's not exaclty a duplicate of [iPhone Programming in Mac OS X runnning not in a Mac Computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133402/iphone-programming-in-mac-os-x-runnning-not-in-a-mac-computer) as it's not stated that it should be on OS X

Answer (score 5):

If it's games you're interested in developing, then another option might be to take a look at Unity (http://unity3d.com/).  This would let you develop on the PC for free in a friendly environment for a beginner.  If you then develop something that you decide you want to publish on iPhone, then at that point you could invest in a Mac and just rebuild the Unity app for iPhone on that.

Also, Unity lets you write scripts in both C# and Java so you wouldn't have to learn Obj-C.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no. The long answer is "not exactly," but you can get started in some ways while you're working on getting access to a Mac you can do the work you'd like to do on.

"XCode" is more or less really two things:

(1) an IDE

(2) a toolchain with a C/ObjC/C++ compiler (really a version of gcc) and a big library of apps

You don't have to use #1 in order to build iPhone Apps, though it's genuinely helpful. You can get by with #2.

But without #2, you're going to have a hard time building an App you can sell in the App store.

So, it depends on what your goal is.

If it really is to build an app and get it out there, the easiest path is probably going to be to find some way to get access to a machine running OS (probably 10.5 and up) you can do development on. That might be talking a friend who has one into letting you spend some scheduled time on it, or it might be working and saving up for a used intel-based Mac mini (probably something you could get for $300), or it might be turning a PC you've got into a [Hackintosh](http://www.hackintosh.com/) (or maybe setting up a Hackintosh VM on the PC if you're sharing it with others who might not want it transformed thusly :).

If your goal is to start learning how to do things while you work out how you're going to do the above, though, the good news is that it's not hard to get a hold of tools that will help you learn the technologies/languages involved in iPhone apps. Like I said earlier, Apple's compiler is really just a version of gcc. You can probably install gcc on your machine and write objective C programs with it. You could also look into [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/) which could help you get familiar with a lot of the concepts and practices underlying how the Cocoa libraries work for the iPhone and OS X. And you could learn OpenGL ES, which would be great help if you ever end up working on an iPhone game.

Answer (score 1):

Actually You can develop apps without a Mac. You can use a number of languages and tools that enable writing apps for iOS like:

```
- Python
- PhoneGap
- Appcelerator
- Mono
- Unity3D
- Unreal Engine
```

These all can export to iOS.

The only step that requires a Mac is publishing to the app store. But You can use any Mac for that, so You can publish from a friend's/neighbour's or actually anyone's Mac. That is the last step when You're sure everything is running perfectly. Perhaps Your application will earn You Your own Mac.

Also there are a number of publishing service providers in the internet (which don't cost nearly as much as a Mac). I don't remember any particular one at the moment, but I'm sure if You search You will find many. Good luck!

Comment: What I like most about this answer is that using C# will also prepare you for cross platform development environments like Xamarin Studio once you do get a mac.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, although there are 'alternatives' (phonegap, mono touch, etc.) I believe you ultimately need Xcode and its tools to package/sign/publish your applications.

If you are really motivated though, you can look about ways of installing Mac OS X on a PC, though that is beyond the scope of this website.

Answer (score 0):

Though Xcode itself is free it does require an Intel based Mac running Snow Leopard. You have 2 options:

- Buy a refurbished Mac Pro or [Mac mini](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/specialdeals/mac?mco=OTY2ODY3Nw) from Apple website. They are not that expensive. You can use non-Apple peripherals with them to bring down the cost. And you will not be disappointed with quality.
- Use [Hackintosh](http://www.osx86project.org/) to run the OS X on other Intel platform. Its hacky, difficult (carshes) and illegal.

Update:

For Objective C you can refer a pretty good documentation of [Objective C language](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) at [iPhone developer portal](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action). There are many other documents like [memory management](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) and [human interface guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) which should help you get started.

Once you have developed the familiarity with Objective C, you can then browse through various programming guides on iPhone development centre. If you want to follow a systematic approach, you may refer to ["Beginning iPhone Development"](http://apress.com/book/view/1430216263) book which I found pretty good.

Comment: so i found out where i'm going to get my mac, so where is a good tutorial for objective-c?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need a mac.  There a number of screwed up ways to do this without a mac, but for all intents and purposes you need a mac.   A mac mini you can buy used for $300 on ebay will do the trick.  You don't need a powerful machine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to develop applications for the mac/ipad/iphone without Xcode and without a mac/ipad/iphone.I own a imac,an ipad,and and a mac book pro.I tried to develop in xcode.

After some quick search on the internet I found this http://www.gnustep.org/. This is a framework you can use to develop in the objective C language,using GCC (the GNU compiler).There are other tools you can use,like GNU STEP Application project:this seems to be a sort of IDE (I didn't test it yet).

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. You can use alternative SDK's but they can be a pain to use and don't offer the publish/signing capabilities that Xcode does.